# laravel - image upload and display issues

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I have a blog post application where I am uploading files to be displayed along with the post itself. I can successfully upload the image but I am unable to display it .

Here is how I am uploading it to a folder within my application..

[image]

and here is how i am displaying it.. 
[image]

I am uploading the image to the uploads folder under my public folder. and I am storing the image in the database as follows.. 
[image]

Although I can see that the image path is correct. I did an echo of the path that is being generated and the path to the image is correct.

Can you please let me know if there is something that I am doing wrong.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
$file = $file->move(public_path() . '/images/uploads',  $filename);
```

to

```
$file = $file->move('images/uploads',  $filename);
```

the above code will upload the picture to the `public_path/images/uploads`.

In your code, i can see you have used full physical path of your image directory to display the picture. Physical path only needed when you are going to upload an image.

**try the following:**

```
<img class="img-responsive" src="/images/uploads/{{ $post->thumbnail }}" >
```

Comment: I would like to upload the images to the public_path of laravel. I can see that the files are getting uploaded but it is not getting displayed on the UI. Hence I think your proposal would not resolve the issue that I am experiencing..

Comment: @Gagan, image will upload to the public path.

Comment: Yup - works . thanks Anam ... marking this as the correct answer... :)

Comment: @Anam please can you help me for this question https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/call-to-member-function-move-on-a-non-object-larvel-52

Answer (score 0):

You are storing the thumbnail within the post model, but are trying to fetch it form the blog model. Try $blog->post->thumbnail instead. (If you have set a relationship)

Comment: sorry - i was using the wrong variable name. Now I have corrected the naming of that variable and posted it again.. thanks